# Ionic Barcode Scanner plugin close button

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on ionic scanner application. i used this [native barcode scanner plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner)  which works perfectly fine. but in this plugin there is no close button on the camera screen. so that i can close the camera if its not necessary. Could someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

that uses cordova plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner in the documentation there are like 10 examples of customization is not that much so you probably have to fork the proyect and change the native code of your platform to add that option